# username and password always wrong, even if they are true in the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, security, password-protection

I'm trying to make a login webpage, and for some reason its always gets into the "false" line where login and password are incorrect. I checked in the database to see maybe I'm a douche, but this is completely true.

This is my code :

```
con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MICROSOF-58B8A5\\SQL_SERVER_R2;Initial Catalog=Daniel;Integrated Security=True");
string query = "SELECT Username, Password FROM Users WHERE Username='" + Username + "' AND Password='" + Password + "'";
con.Open();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
adap.Fill(ds);
int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
if (count == 0)
{
    ErrorMessege.Text = "Username or Password was Incorrect!";
}
else
{
    Session["Session"] = UsernameLogin.Text;
    Response.Redirect("MenuHome.aspx");
}
con.Close();
```

Thanks for the helpers!

Comment: Use `SqlParameter`s to pass the UserName and Password values to the query! Your current implementation is asking for SQL injection! (for example, try entering `x' and 1=1 --` as the user name and some random value for the password to see what happens)

Comment: Why not just use the built in asp.net sql membership provider?

Comment: I'd like to be user `'x';DROP TABLE Users;`

Comment: Storing passwords in the clear? I wouldn't want to subscribe to your login system. What's wrong with the default AspNet MembershipProvider? Rolling your own login system seems like a big waste of time and a great way to introduce security issues. A cursory glance at your code reveals 2 serious problems (at least)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks like it should work. Have you stepped through it and added a watch on ds to see what values it has? I executed the code on my machine against one of my test DBs and it worked fine.

I would however suggest something similair to this as it is a lot cleaner in my opinion:

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MICROSOF-58B8A5\\SQL_SERVER_R2;Initial Catalog=Daniel;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    string query = "SELECT TOP 1 Username FROM Users WHERE Username=@UserName AND Password=@Password";

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", UserName);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password);
        con.Open();
        string username = (string)command.ExecuteScalar(); //Add Null Check
        // Do stuff if username exists         
    }
}
```

You should always add a using statement on an object that implements IDisposable.(SqlConnection, SqlCommand) Also to prevent SqlInjection and the likes, use parameterized queries.

Comment: He still needs to fix is password storage. You fixed the sql-injection, but not that he stores plain text passwords.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to check for passwords is by just creating an SqlDataReader created from

```
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
var reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteDataReader();
if(reader.Read()){
 //you got a correct password, read fields from reader
   string username = reader[0];
}
```

[ExecuteReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k.aspx)
[SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to Response.Write the query string and then paste the result into a new query in the database explorer? You might be surprised :)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the username and password validation is not case-sensitive or validate it with the correct case. If the DB uses case-sensitive collation, it may not return what you expecting.

Comment: I ensured that its written just like in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Few things to check:

1. case (upper/lower) of the username/password value you are sending; probably due to case insensitivity it's not matching anything.
2. Are you storing password in plain text format ... generally password would be stored encrypted ... So I would suggest you to search for username only like

   SELECT Username, Password FROM Users WHERE lower(Username) ='Username';

Comment: Nitpick: You don't encrypt passwords, you hash them.